# footnote from within halign

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, plain-tex

How do you create a footnote within an halign in plain TeX?

The code below produces a line that looks like this:

A  B  C<sup>2</sup>

which is as it should be, but the footnote reading ``How is this?'' simply does not appear.

```
\centerline{\vbox{
\halign{\hfil #\hfil & \hfil #\hfil & \hfil # \hfil\cr
A & B & C\footnote{$^2$}{How is this}\cr}}}
```

(I have found answers for the analogous question re LaTeX, but this is a plain TeX question.)

Comment: the halign is not the problem, you need to remove the centerline and vbox.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :  Aha!  Right you are.  Thank you.  Is there some other way to horizontally center this halign and still have the footnote work?

Comment: (I tried using \matrix in display math mode, but had exactly the same issue.  I suppose the display math is automatically inside the same kinds of boxes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Footnotes do not migrate out of vboxes (A:), so use just use `\halign` (B:), or use `\vfootnote` outside the box (C:).

```
A:

\centerline{\vbox{
 \halign{\hfil #\hfil & \hfil #\hfil & \hfil # \hfil\cr
A & B & C\footnote{$^2$}{How is this2}\cr}}}

B:

{\tabskip0pt plus1fill\relax
\halign to\hsize{\tabskip0pt\hfil #\hfil & \hfil #\hfil & \hfil # \hfil\tabskip0pt plus1fill\relax\cr
A & B & C\footnote{$^3$}{How is this3}\cr}}

C:

\centerline{\vbox{
\halign{\hfil #\hfil & \hfil #\hfil & \hfil # \hfil\cr
A & B & C$^4$\cr}}}
\vfootnote{$^4$}{How is this4}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you again.